# Cannot retrieve value of Textbox on Update method

Tags: c#, gridview, sql-update

I want to update this form's Login and Logout Time:

[image]

My code is :

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LoginTime = txtIn.Text;
    string LogOutTime = txtOut.Text;
    long DayLogId = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["ID"]); 

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
    dataConnection.ConnectionString =@"Data Source=DELL\SQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=LoginSystem;Integrated Security=True";

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand();
    dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;

    //tell the compiler and database that we're using parameters (thus the @first, @last, @nick)  
    dataCommand.CommandText = ("UPDATE [DayLog] SET [LoginTime]=@LoginTime,[LogOutTime]=@LogOutTime WHERE [DayLogId]=@DayLogId");

    //add our parameters to our command object  
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginTime", LoginTime);
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogOutTime", LogOutTime);
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DayLogId", DayLogId);


    dataConnection.Open();
    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dataConnection.Close();
}
```

At the first two lines of method ,

```
    string LoginTime = txtIn.Text;
    string LogOutTime = txtOut.Text;
```

when I debug , it does not show the value that I reinserted. This code works if I mannually write

```
    string LoginTime = "11:44:11";
    string LogOutTime = "12:44:11";
```

**NOTE:**

The value of forms in text box is coming from another page GridView.

```
protected void grdEmployee_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "View")
    {
        GridViewRow grRow = ((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        Label DayLogId = grRow.FindControl("lblDayLogId") as Label;
        if (Convert.ToInt16(DayLogId.Text) > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Employee/OutLog_Day.aspx?ID=" + DayLogId.Text, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the association between the gridview and the form? does the update of one should trigger the update of the other?

Comment: This is a symptom often linked to a missing IsPostBack test on the Page_Load event

Comment: post your page load event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that the text box gets populated before the click event runs. As Steve suggested, usually you get this when you initialize the data on every postback which is unnecessary if the data is not changed.